# Why is JavaScript function documentation outside the function?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

In JavaScript, most documentation formats seem to put a block above the function:

```
/**
 * example JavaScript docstring
 */
function myFunction(){...}
```

(example: [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html))

In Python however, most documentation formats use documentation *inside* the function body:

```
def my_function():
    """ Do amazing things
    """
    (function body here)
```

(example: [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings))

Coming from a Python background, this seems like a far more practical format, because:

1. you don't have to maintain all of the `*`stars and their spacing
2. it's easier for documentation generators to introspect by grabbing the body of the function
3. the function signature naturally becomes "part" of the documentation, since it's right there and you can read the function name before the docs without scrolling past first.

Why is the convention to put the docs outside the function in JavaScript? My guess is that it's a holdover from older languages but I'd like a more compelling reason than that. I'm hoping there's an interesting historical or practical reason for this. Enlighten me!

Answer (score 4):

The docstring in Python is a feature of the language itself.  I mean, Python itself detects a string at the top of a class or function and stores that string as `function.__doc__`.

So the documentation of the function is stored with the function, so you can do `help(function)` to read it in the interpreter.

That's how easy the introspection is in Python. Classes and functions are objects, so you just access their `__doc__` variable and voilà, you have the docstring.

Javascript never decided to add such a feature, so the documentation is NOT available at interpretation time and it needs to be extracted from the source code file by a documentation generator utility.  This sort of makes sense for a language optimized for running in the browser -- most of the time you don't even want to load the documentation text.

Even so, Javascript documentation frameworks could and should have placed documentation comments inside the function, not outside it.  One of the benefits of such placement is that when I use code folding in my editor I would see only function names (I don't want to see any documentation in that case).  It is better to see the start of documentation text only when I hover my mouse on top of a function that interests me.

I guess the reason the frameworks did not choose the best placement for documentation comments is... they did not have this idea.  You can think of this as the [Blub Paradox](https://wiki.c2.com/?BlubParadox) in miniature: if you didn't experience the advantages of Python, you are oblivious (even in denial of) them.  This applies even to ergonomics -- witness the legions of programmers saying they dislike meaningful whitespace which rids the code of ugly curly braces that are manually maintained...  And every human parses code through its indentation, not through its curly braces...

By the way, it is not true that Python lacks multiline comments (as asserted elsewhere in this page), since you can just write a multiline string anywhere you want in the code without assigning the string to any variable, and for all intents and purposes it looks like a comment.  Further, Javascript does have concrete multiline comments, but what documentation framework really uses those?  I mean, one of our complaints is having to maintain hundreds of asterisks...  Great good the multiline comments did to Javascript, huh?

Answer (score 1):

The format used in JS comes from the C background of the language, since multiline comments are supported out-of-the-box it makes things easier.

Keep in mind that it's more of an aesthetic choice than a technical choice, so it doesn't necessarily have a definite, clear explanation.

Comment: Also, since commenting standards are something that every developer has to spend time on, and since the style affects its consumability and maintainability, one could argue that it's a technical choice as much as an aesthetic one: your team will go faster or slower based on how easy your docs are to consume and maintain.